# How do i make that when I make an instance of a new class, it must get a parameter?

Tags: c#

For example:

```
class WebCrawler
{
    List<string> currentCrawlingSite;
    List<string> sitesToCrawl;
    RetrieveWebContent retwebcontent;

    public WebCrawler()
    {
    }
}
```

When I  make `WebCrawler = new WebCrawler(parameter here)`...

Comment: Put a parameter in constructor: `public WebCrawler(string parameter){}`

Comment: These kind of questions do not belong here, please read at least somee basic tutorial or a book on C# and class design.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add another *constructor* to your class;

```
public WebCrawler(parameter here)
{
}
```

After that, you need to **remove** parameterless one constructor, so people can create an instance of your class without provide any parameters.

You can create an instance of it like

`WebCrawler w = new WebCrawler(parameter here);`

You can read for more informations from [`Instance Constructors`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/k6sa6h87.aspx)

Here is a [`DEMO`](http://ideone.com/2ViRWt).

Comment: OP says "*It must get a parameter*". Doesn't that mean removing the parameterless constructors as well as adding a new one?

Comment: @mattytommo Yeah, you are right. Since question isn't clear as well, my fault.. Updated..

Answer (score 2):

Create constructor with parameter you want to be provided by user:

```
public WebCrawler(string param1, int param2)
{
}
```

When any constructor like that is added the default one (parameterless) is no longer available, unless you write it yourself:

```
public WebCrawler()
{
}
```

So just **remove it**, and user won't be able to create your class instance object without providing these parameters. You can also make the same setting parameterless constructor `private` or `protected`.

[Instance Constructors (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/k6sa6h87.aspx)

Comment: +1 For being the only one who says remove the empty one, as the OP did say a value **must** be passed.

Answer (score 2):

You can make the parameter-less constructor `private`...

```
private WebCrawler()
{
}
```

Meaning no consumers/callers have the ability to call it.

You then have only one constructor that they can use:

```
public WebCrawler(string something)
{
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add another constructor accepting a parameter:

```
public WebCrawler(string someParameter)
{

}
```